# Run Homebridge on crontab

Tags: networking, cron, raspberrypi

I have installed homebridge on my Raspberry and want to run it on startup, so I added

```
crontab -e
@reboot homebridge &
```

to the crontab file. But on reboot the PI always stops at the login form (understandable) but even after logging in I don’t see homebridge running, I have activated the option to finish reboot only on network connection, because I want to make it headless and add other server features later.

Do I have to deactivate the login as well?

Comment: In changed the line from ˋcrontab to ˋsudo crontabˋ but nothing changed

Comment: I don't know what `homebridge` is or does, but generally you shouldn't need to login before systems services can start.

Comment: Oh sorry, homebridge is a node.js server

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but according to [this](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/wiki/Install-Homebridge-on-Debian-or-Ubuntu-Linux#step-6-create-systemd-service) `homebridge` is a system service, meaning that it is automatically started at boot time. You shouldn't need to add it through the `crontab`. Instead, find out why it doesn't run by itself, by entering `sudo systemctl status homebridge`.

Comment: Oh thanks for the clarification, I didn’t know about services, the command tells me that no homebridge.service was found. I will dig into it to find out how to add this service